# Exception getting zoo instance in geomesa accumulo data store

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, accumulo, geomesa

Thanks for your attention. I am setting up  Accumulo Data Store using geomesa and zookeper and have completed set up configuration changes and installed required instance like accumulo, java and maven.
When I am creating a new feature using command line interface using command `geomesa create-schema -u root -p ****** \
-c device_ping \
-f feature \
-s uuid:String:index=true,dtg:Date,geom:Point:srid=4326 \
--dtg dtg`

It fails giving

> Exception getting zoo instance and terminate throwing error "Unable to create data store, please check your connection parameters."

I am unable to find solution to this problem and don't know which configuration parameters are wrong. Here is the details of attached screenshot[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoMesa works to figure out the Zookeepers from a local copy of the Accumulo cluster's configuration.  That configuration is likely in $ACCUMULO_HOME.

You can manually set the zookeepers with -z host1,host2,host3.  If the hosts are correct (or you set them manually), you might check that zookeeper is running and can be accessed from your laptop.

To double check Zookeeper, you can do something like...

```
echo ruok | nc hostName portNumber
```

If Zookeeper is running, you'll receive an 'imok' message back.

Lastly, if Zookeeper is up and running, but just slow for some reason, you can increase the Zookeeper timeout by setting the Java system property "instance.zookeeper.timeout" higher.  The timeout is currently set to 5 seconds.